# terminating with uncaught exception: NSException

Tags: ios, swift

Swift app crashes and gives me this error.

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Modifications to the layout engine must not be performed from a background thread after it has been accessed from the main thread.'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1aa5a980c 0x1aa2d1fa4 0x1aaa7ff1c 0x1aa88ad64 0x1aa88ac7c 0x1aa88a8f0 0x1aeaa6c34 0x1aeaa766c 0x1b0ff578c 0x1b0ffb908 0x1b1006528 0x1b0f4eed0 0x1b0f78bbc 0x1b0f79b40 0x1aa2c9344 0x1aa2c622c 0x1aa2c7280 0x1aa2c7018 0x1aa2c9ad4)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Now the issue I have is I don't know what is firing this error.

I can only think it is happening inside the news section of the script as it was not happening in the original script when I was going from screen to screen.

I know it is something on the newsViewController causing it to fire.

[image: Crash]

here is the view controller script for the news.

```
//
//  NewsViewController.swift
//  DRN1
//
//  Created by Russell Harrower on 26/11/19.
//  Copyright © 2019 Russell Harrower. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit


struct NewsData: Decodable{
    let news: [articalData]
}

struct articalData: Decodable{
    let title: String
}

class NewsViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    var news: [News] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()

        self.newsfetch { [weak self] news in
            guard let news = news else { return }
            self?.news = news
            self?.tableView.reloadData()
        }

        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
    }

    func createArray() -> [News] {

           return [News(title: "Hello") , News(title: "how") , News(title: "You")]

    }

    func newsfetch(_ completionHandler:  @escaping ([News]?)->Void){
        let jsonURLString = "https://api.drn1.com.au/api-access/news"
        guard let feedurl = URL(string: jsonURLString) else {  return }

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: feedurl){ (data,response,err)
            in
            guard let news = data else { return }
            do {
                let newsdata = try JSONDecoder().decode(NewsData.self, from: news)
                var tempNews: [News] = []
                newsdata.news.forEach(){
                    tempNews.append(News(title: $0.title))
                }
                completionHandler(tempNews)
            } catch let jsonErr {
                print("error json ", jsonErr)
                completionHandler(nil)
            }
        }.resume()

    }


    /*func newsfetch() -> [News]{

        var tempNews: [News] = []
                    let jsonURLString = "https://api.drn1.com.au/api-access/news"
                    guard let feedurl = URL(string: jsonURLString) else {  return tempNews }

                      URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: feedurl) { (data,response,err)
                          in

                          guard let news = data else { return }

                          do{
                            let newsdata = try JSONDecoder().decode(NewsData.self, from: news)

                            newsdata.news.forEach(){

                                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                    print($0.title)

                                    tempNews.append(News(title: $0.title))
                                    print(tempNews.count)
                                }
                            }
                            }catch let jsonErr{

                                print("error json ", jsonErr)
                            }


                      }.resume()



        return tempNews

        }*/


  override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    self.tabBarController?.navigationItem.title = "News"




  }

}


extension NewsViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return news.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let newsa = news[indexPath.row]

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "NewsCell") as! NewsCell
        cell.setNews(news: newsa)
        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: Reload the table on main thread !

Comment: @ShivamGaur how?

Comment: change your tableview.reloadData line to this line - DispatchQueue.main.async { self.?.tableView.reloadData() }

Comment: DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to reload your tableView on main thread. As the error suggests, Modifications to the layout engine should always be done through main thread.

change your tableview.reloadData line to this line -

```
DispatchQueue.main.async { 
self?.tableView.reloadData() 
}
```